# ignoreAnchorPointForPosition method in cocos seems to be not working

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am setting

`ignoreAnchorPointForPosition = YES;`

then after that setting my layer scale with

```
[self runAction: [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.35 scale:node.scale-0.3]];
```

but my layer sifted right side at the time of scale out . 
so I think that ignoreAnchorPointForPosition=yes not affect-able .

Comment: Reset the anchor point to (0.5, 0.5) before running the action and then restore it to the desired value in the completion block for the action.

Comment: I already tried this but it also gives the same problem . Layer shifter right side again .

Comment: The ignoreAnchorPointForPosition is a BOOL that is only set by CCScene and CCLayer. If this flag is set, it treats the anchorPoint as being at 0x0 for all position related properties and methods.
This flag allows both CCScene and CCLayer to have their position property remain at 0x0 while having their anchorPoint at 0.5x0.5 - this allows the scenes and layers to rotate and scale around the center of the screen, which is needed for some transition animations and actions.

Comment: be mindful with your tags, you are obviously using cocos2d-iphone yet you used the tags: cocos2d-x sprite-kit cocos2d-android. Why?

Comment: ooh sorry i will further remember .